# Python OOP different method names

Tags: python, oop

I want to implement a class and 2 subclasses:

```
class cars(object):
    def chassis(self):
        ...

class automobile(cars):
    def chassisAutomobile(self):
        ...

class truck(cars):
    def chassisTruck(self):
        ...
```

The methods "chassisAutomobile" and "chassisTruck" should have the same featuers than "chassis" + additional (for the subclass special) features.
I guess it would be simple, if they would have the same name - but in my application it would make sence, that they have different names (chassis - chassisAutomobile, chassisTruck).

How would you implement this in Python?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: "But in my application it would make sence, that they have different names" why so? Do real trucks have both a chassis AND a truck chassis?

Comment: Also, you should consider naming your classes in singular form and with `CamelCase`, so for example, instead of `cars` you should use the name `Car`.

Comment: What problems are you facing with that? If you want to call `chassis` from `chassisTruck`, just do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the same name `chassis()` for all of them, since it's not like trucks have both, a car's chassis and a truck's chassis:

```
class cars(object):
    def chassis(self):
        pass  # Do cars stuff

class automobile(cars):
    def chassis(self):
        super().chassis()
        # Do automobile stuff

class truck(cars):
    def chassis(self):
        super().chassis()
        # Do truck stuff
```

However, if you're sure you need separate names (so `truck` can use both `chassis()` and `chassisTruck()`), you can just call `self.chassis()` inside of your `chassisTruck` and `chassisAutomobile`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have access to the `.chassis()` method in both of your subclasses since you extend the `cars` class. You can write your class specific code, then simply call `.chassis()` at the end (or beginning). For example:

```
class cars(object):
    def chassis(self):
        ...common code here...

class automobile(cars):
    def chassisAutomobile(self):
        ...do things...
        self.chassis()

class truck(cars):
    def chassisTruck(self):
        ...do things...
        self.chassis()
```

As an unrelated side note; it is a good idea to begin class names with capital letters, per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).